# listbox selected item in a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have two listboxes, two text boxes and buttons. When I press the buttons the items of list box 1 is moved to list box2 but i want to display the selected items in the textfields so how do i do it??

```
txtbox.Text = listbox3.selecteditem.value;
```

is not working, i also tried

```
txtbox.Text = listbox3.selecteditem.tostring();
```

this is my piece of code. 'm a fresher and new to asp .net

```
if (RadioButton1.Checked == true)
{
  a = ListBox3.SelectedValue.ToString();
  b = ListBox3.SelectedIndex;
  ListBox4.Items.Add(a);
  ListBox3.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox3.Items.IndexOf((ListBox3.SelectedItem)));

  TextBox1.Text = RadioButton1.Text.ToString();
  TextBox2.Text = ListBox3.SelectedItem.Value;
}
```

Comment: yes but the 1st two 'm not using them now

Comment: so u want to value to show in second textbox, the value that is removed from ListBox3?

Comment: yes your rite. that is what i want to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (RadioButton1.Checked == true)
{    
            var a = ListBox3.SelectedValue.ToString();
            var b = ListBox3.SelectedIndex;

            ListBox4.Items.Add(a);
            ListBox3.Items.RemoveAt(b);

            TextBox1.Text = RadioButton1.Text.ToString();
            TextBox2.Text = a;
}
```

addtionally, i would suggest you to check the `SelectedIndex` value, if none item is selected in the `ListBox`, the `SelectedIndex` will be `-1`

Better version of your code

```
if (RadioButton1.Checked == true)
{    


    var b = ListBox3.SelectedIndex;
    var a = ListBox3.SelectedValue.ToString();

    if (b < 0)
    {
        // no ListBox item selected;
        return;
    }

    ListBox4.Items.Add(a);
    ListBox3.Items.RemoveAt(b);

    TextBox1.Text = RadioButton1.Text.ToString();
    TextBox2.Text = a;
}
```

Comment: @user1986144 - do mark the answer as solved if it helped you!

Comment: ok surely 'l try tis and this validation was somthing that i required thank u :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

U need to edit the last line of code...
Most Probably it goes like this.... Use "GetSelectedItem" instead of "SelectedItem"

```
TextBox2.Text = ListBox3.GetSelectedItem.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that you need to assign first the selected value to a string. Then assign that string to a textbox.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string value1 = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    TextBox1.Text=value1;
}
```

Hope it helps!